# sending multiple parameters in "withParameters:" call

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Hello I need to know how to send two objects through a withParameters: method.

Here is my code:

```
    NSDictionary *numberparam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:phoneNumber  forKey:@"number"];
    NSDictionary *messageparam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"message"];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"inviteWithTwilio" withParameters:numberparam messageparam block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        NSString *message1 = @"";
```

Everything works fine if I take out messageparam from the PFCloud call but I need to include it.  How do i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd put them in a dictionary together:

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
params[@"number"] = phoneNumber;
params[@"message"] = message;
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"inviteWithTwilio" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
    NSString *message1 = @""; 
}];
```

Then, in cloud use

```
var phoneNumber = request.number;
var message = request.message;
```

Comment: incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'NSDictionary *'

Comment: Did you see the update, my first original array answer was wrong. I tried to update before you saw it!