# Can not Sending multiple parameters from iOS to Cloud Code

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Not error happen but when I run program it crash.

**App Code**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *CurrentDate;

- (void) GetCalUsed{
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
CurrentDate = [NSDate date];
params[@"user"] = user.objectId;
params[@"date"] = CurrentDate;
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"CalUsed"
                   withParameters:params
                            block:^(NSNumber *CalUsed1, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"Calories : %@",CalUsed1);
                                    CalUsed = CalUsed1;
                                    NSLog(@"Selected Date : %@",CurrentDate);


                                }

                            }];
```

}

**Cloud code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("CalUsed", function(request, response) {
var user = request.user;
var date = request.date;
var query = new Parse.Query("FoodLog");

query.equalTo("user",user);
query.equalTo("Date",date);
               query.find({
                          success: function(results) {
                          var sum = 0;
                          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                          sum += results[i].get("Calories");
                          }
                          response.success(sum);
                          },
                          error: function() {
                          response.error("lookup failed");
                          }
                          });
               });
```

I tried follow this method [sending multiple parameters in "withParameters:" call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396963/sending-multiple-parameters-in-withparameters-call) but it's doesn't worked.

Comment: Which line does it crash at?

Comment: it solve when i used 
    var user = request.user;
    var date = request.params.date;

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `.params`after request and before your dictionary key:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("CalUsed", function(request, response) {
var user = request.params.user;
var date = request.params.date;
var query = new Parse.Query("FoodLog");

query.equalTo("user",user);
query.equalTo("Date",date);
               query.find({
                          success: function(results) {
                          var sum = 0;
                          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                          sum += results[i].get("Calories");
                          }
                          response.success(sum);
                          },
                          error: function() {
                          response.error("lookup failed");
                          }
                          });
               });
```

Comment: thank you it's worked
    var user = request.user;
    var date = request.params.date;